# How to only select one option at a time from radio button in Reac Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Im using galio's radio component [this here](https://galio.io/docs/#/components/radio). Im trying to select only one value at a time. I try to achieve that with this code:

```
const [selected, setSelected ] = useState(false);
const OptionList = (groupOption) => {
   return (
     <FlatList
       data={groupOption.options}
       keyExtractor={(result) => result.id.toString()}
       renderItem={({ item }) => {
         return (
           <View>
             <Radio label={item.description} onChange={() => setSelected(true)} initialValue={selected} />
           </View>
         );
       }}
     />
   );
 };
```

But since its in a flat list it changes the value for all of them. How can i only select one radio button at a time? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use Radio Group or save the selected index in the state, when the user clicks on the radio button, change that selected index and mark it selected.

Comment: Yeah i thought of that but the framework doesnt have it as a component. Will try to do the second suggestion

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-radio-buttons-group I think that's what you are looking for

an example

> ```
> import React, { useState } from 'react';
> import RadioGroup from 'react-native-radio-buttons-group';
>
> const radioButtonsData = [{
>     id: '1', // acts as primary key, should be unique and non-empty string
>     label: 'Option 1',
>     value: 'option1'
> }, {
>     id: '2',
>     label: 'Option 2',
>     value: 'option2'
> }]
>
> export default function App() {
>
>     const [radioButtons, setRadioButtons] = useState(radioButtonsData)
>
>     function onPressRadioButton(radioButtonsArray) {
>         setRadioButtons(radioButtonsArray);
>     }
>
>     return (
>         <RadioGroup 
>             radioButtons={radioButtons} 
>             onPress={onPressRadioButton} 
>         />
>     );
>
> }
> ```